# I have a depression in my OSB floor caused by a layer of rot

Tags: flooring

I am tiling over OSB board using hardiboard and thinset. I have some water damage from a leaking toilet. The rotted area is about 3 inches square. Once I scraped about a half inch of rot off the top, the floor is still very solid. I don't feel it is necessary to remove the flooring. However, I need to fill it in now so the floor is level before I apply the hardiboard.

What is the best way to do this? Can I just build up the thinset in that spot before I lay the backerboard?  The depression is 1/4"-1/2" deep at most.

Answer (score 1):

A 3x3 repair using the technique you describe is just fine, assuming that it's not in a critical location, such as immediately adjacent to the toilet drain opening. If it is, you might find that the stress of the toilet on that spot results in too much flex. In that case, cut the area out and float some lumber under the patch edges and replace the piece.

Otherwise you're unlikely to have a problem. Thinset mortar won't provide much stiffness, but it's certainly hard enough to  do the job.

Comment: I wonder if by rot the op ment swollen and falling apart? That's what I have found with osb more often than rot.

Comment: Could be, but the situation is the same if all loose material has been removed.

Comment: True with swollen material I have cleaned it up and used thinset if there were no other problems found, I like bonding my backer with thinset any way so filling a small void is not much different.+

Comment: I would add, you should use an anti-mold encapsulation spray and cover the area before applying the thinset.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some **[Durham's Rock Hard Water Putty](https://www.lowes.com/pd/durham-s-64-fl-oz-light-yellow-patching-and-spackling-compound/3143343?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-pnt-_-google-_-lia-_-133-_-wallrepair-_-3143343-_-0&kpid&store_code=749&k_clickID=go_625682584_34615018630_111134780950_aud-299487635210:pla-260326515081_c_9013288&gclid=Cj0KCQiA7briBRD7ARIsABhX8aDf0qcGGHhcPgYqF0PCVkRAnlCCpZzIer_K_s5sBJpGrXkz_eZGRRwaAocfEALw_wcB)**. Mixes up easy, doesn't shrink and you can sand or paint it.

[image: Durham's Water Putty]

Comment: How is this preferable to the thinset mortar?

Comment: @isherwood : it doesn't shrink.  Thinset does, so you often have to apply multiple coats to get it even.

Answer (score 0):

I would just cut off a 4x4 section of the subfloor and put a new piece of OSB. It is much easier, faster, and more sturdy than trying to fill the wood you have removed.  Make sure you cut where the trusses are.  Why risk it on a new floor?